# Facebook login for Swift project

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am prompting my users to sign in through Facebook to obtain their profile picture for the app's profile. This is the code I have for requesting a Facebook sign in:

```
func facebookSignIn() {
    //Current user that's logged in from sign up view
    let currUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    //Create a Facebook session
    FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(permission, allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: {
        (session, status, error) -> Void in
            FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler {(connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if result != nil && result.objectID != nil {
                    //Create a column in Parse called "facebookID"
                    currUser!.setObject(result.objectID as String, forKey: "facebookID")
                    currUser!.saveInBackground()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

It worked fine before I turned the app from Development Mode to Public. Now, every time I click my "Sign in on Facebook" button, it takes me to Safari with the Facebook page and says **"Error. Not logged in: You are not logged in. Please login and try again"**

Anyone have any idea what this issue could be? The log in page doesn't prompt up anymore.

Comment: I have resolved the problem. Please check out the "update" section in my answer.

Comment: This looks VERY promising. Spent all night yesterday trying to fix it. I will come back with hopefully good news once I try your solution.

Comment: It should work, since it helped me to solve the exact same problem.

Comment: YUP! IT'S FIXED! Thank you so much, @driver733. You are a homie for life.

Comment: Haha! I'm glad I could help! Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are trying to implement Facebook login using Facebook and Parse iOS SDK. I am not sure if it is really necessary for you to use FBSession and FBRequestConnection to do a login. There are actually two ways you could go. The first one is to simply use [Parse Facebook Utils](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users) to process login. Or you could implement login via Facebook iOS SDK. Below you can find code for the second option coupled with user registration.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "fb:", name: FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification, object: nil) // hi! we have logged in! so we can get profile picture in "fb" function (since FBSDKProfile.currentProfile() which we loaded asynchronously is now fully downloaded)
}

@IBAction func loginWithFacebook(sender: AnyObject) { // button for login
    let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email", "public_profile", "user_friends"], handler: {
        (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil && result.token != nil {
            // logged in
        } else {
            // process error
        }
    })
}

func fb(notif:NSNotification){ // access token has changed! We have logged in or logged out
    if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil { // Are we logged in?
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken(), block: { // Let`s login the fb user with parse (using acquired fb access token)
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew { // user is new? Then let`s register in Parse
                    let smallProfileImage = FBSDKProfile.currentProfile().imagePathForPictureMode(FBSDKProfilePictureMode.Normal, size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))  // // get user profile picture in a small size
                    let bigProfileImage = FBSDKProfile.currentProfile().imagePathForPictureMode(FBSDKProfilePictureMode.Normal, size: CGSizeMake(600, 600)) // get user profile picture in a big size
                    user.setObject("https://graph.facebook.com/\(smallProfileImage)", forKey: "smallProfileImage") // set user`s small image (link)
                    user.setObject("https://graph.facebook.com/\(bigProfileImage)", forKey: "bigProfileImage") // set user`s small image (link)
                    PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user, withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) // save the user in Parse
                }
            } else {
                print("Uh oh. There was an error logging in.")
            }
        })

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**: It seems that I have figured it out. Go to [Facebook dev portal page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) and choose your app. On the left side panel, select "settings". Check all app info and especially the "Bundle ID" (if it is correct, replace it with another one, save settings and then put the correct one back in). If the issue is still present, please go your Facebook app main page and go through the "Get Started with the Facebook SDK" guide (and check if the bundle identifier is correct when it is prompted). Also, in "Client OAuth Settings" (Advanced tab on top) the only thing I have enabled is `Client OAuth Login`

Comment: Thanks for the code. I might go with using the Parse Facebook Utils option. I'm also not sure if the code I wrote is needed, but it's strange - I was able to get all the Facebook stuff to work before, but why did it suddenly stop working?

Comment: Honesty, I have no idea why you would implement fb login that way. Try to [use official documents and guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.4). In your case, I would advise you to play around with your Facebook app. The cause might be [Facebook App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review) (Facebook limits your api functionality significantly unless your app gets reviewed by Facebook.) Also, please be aware that using parse Facebook utils will slightly increase your [request limits](https://www.parse.com/questions/burst-limit).

Comment: I tried implementing it in another way. It's the same exact issue. Safari opens the Facebook browser, but it still says Not Logged In. Does it have to do with something with the Bundle ID/Facebook ID/Info.plist?

Comment: Try to use [Facebook pre-made login button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.4#login-button), just to make sure the issue is not in your implementation. If it still produces the same result, then check Bundle ID/Facebook ID/Info.plist. Or maybe setup a new project for fb login testing purposes. Please do not rely on safari for login (it`s against app store rules). Use UIWebView or fb native app (both available in fb sdk). Try switching your fb back to dev mode. If everything works again, then your app has to be reviewed by fb before you can use all api functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know if I made any progress.

Comment: Apparently, you seem to bring bad luck :) I have just checked my own existing app and Facebook (in UIWebView) instantly says your exact error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should read about `FBSDKLoginButton` [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.4) because that's what Facebook tells you to use when you want to login with Facebook in your app not `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions`